# Capturing Paypal payment always fails with PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED in production

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Several weeks ago, we started seeing failed payments with our old Paypal Express integration without making any changes to it. They did not fail 100% but maybe 80%-90%. It seemed to fail arbitrarily.

We followed the [upgrade path](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/upgrade-integration/) for the new Checkout integration, but kept seeing the same errors.

Finally we went all in on the new Standard (*not Advanced!*) Checkout integration using the Orders v2 API, replacing the old Payments V1 API. But that did not change anything either.

**Side note:** All of the integrations (old, updated, new) work totally fine in Sandbox.

But in production, almost every capture request fails with a `PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED` error.

Here are the the steps:

User clicks on the checkout with paypal button.

The button's `createOrder()` method calls our server and we create an order with a POST to https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders, with the following response:

```
{
  id: '1KC867444K565180X',
  status: 'CREATED',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1KC867444K565180X',
      rel: 'self',
      method: 'GET'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=1KC867444K565180X',
      rel: 'approve',
      method: 'GET'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1KC867444K565180X',
      rel: 'update',
      method: 'PATCH'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1KC867444K565180X/capture',
      rel: 'capture',
      method: 'POST'
    }
  ]
}
```

We **do not** redirect to the `approve` URL (since the button should handle it on the frontend, right?). So we just hand the ID back to the button's `createOrder()` method.

The `onApprove()` callback then calls our server again with the orderId and the paymentId. We do not capture the payment yet. Instead, we fetch the details to get the shipping address. After calculating the shipping costs, we PATCH the order. Then we fetch details again and verify that all changes have been applied correctly - which ist the case.

**Side note:** When fetching details after creating the order (so after it went through the buttons `onApprove()` callback, and right before capturing), there is no more `approve` link listed:

```
{
  id: '1KC867444K565180X',
  intent: 'CAPTURE',
  status: 'APPROVED',
  purchase_units: [
    {
      //...
    }
  ],
  payer: {
     //...
  },
  create_time: '2022-07-14T14:41:16Z',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1KC867444K565180X',
      rel: 'self',
      method: 'GET'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1KC867444K565180X',
      rel: 'update',
      method: 'PATCH'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1KC867444K565180X/capture',
      rel: 'capture',
      method: 'POST'
    }
  ]
}
```

Up until now, sandbox and production behave excatly the same. But when we now try to capture the payment, sandbox works fine, but production returns this:

```
{
  name: 'UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY',
  details: [
    {
      issue: 'PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED',
      description: 'Payer needs to perform the following action before proceeding with payment.'
    }
  ],
  message: 'The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.',
  debug_id: '160e81e8cc53f',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED',
      rel: 'information_link',
      method: 'GET'
    }
  ]
}
```

We completely ran out of ideas what to do with this message. The docs suggest that "*The order requires an action from the payer (e.g. 3DS authentication). Redirect the payer to the "rel":"payer-action" HATEOAS link returned as part of the response prior to authorizing or capturing the order.*" - but there is no such link. Plus, the order status is already `APPROVED`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to having patched the order before capture, requiring re-approval.

---

Adapt the error handling code in [this demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) to also call `actions.restart()` when the issue is PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED .

Essentially,

```js
if (errorDetail && ['INSTRUMENT_DECLINED', 'PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED'].includes(errorDetail.issue) ) {
```

---

Alternatively, instead of the button JS you can use the `rel:approve` href from the original order creation and redirect to that.

Comment: Thnanks, unfortunately that didn't do the trick (redirecting server side). If we redirect to the approve URL, the user gets stuck there. So when clicking on "Continue", it basically just reloads the same page. Also, I'm not quite sure how this would be related to patching the order before capturing. We've been doing so for years without any issues. Also, it seems to work *sometimes*. We've tried several attempts with the same account. The first one succeeded, the second one failed, the third one succeeded again. Might Paypal have change something on their end?

Comment: You need to specify a application_context return_url in the original order creation request (and handle that return event) if you are going to be redirecting away. The above code is for not redirecting away.

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved the issue. But still kind of weird that sandbox and production behaviour are so massively different. But as @Shaorn pointed out in her answer, it's basically just an EU thing, so I guess that kind of explains it. Anyway, thanks again, appreciate the quick help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

this error is due to the EBA PSD2.0 regulation. any order is paid through credit card issued from EMEA region, and the capture amount is higher than the  create order amount, it will be declined with the error code. here's the PayPal change about the over capture:
https://www.paypal.com/ae/smarthelp/article/FAQ4645

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the explanation I was looking for!

Comment: no worries. we are currently facing with the same problem. the success rate dropped sharply in EMEA region. it will be happy to discuss the solution if you already had one.

Comment: We basically now do what @Preston PHX suggested. We catch the `PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED` status on capture, and in that case we just create a new Order with the full amount (which is known at this point). We also set the `application_context` with a cancel_url and return_url, as well as user_action = 'PAY_NOW'. Then we just redirect to the new approve url. This all happens server side. So in the end, the user is presented the Paypal approval page twice, but that's as good as it gets if you don't know the total amount up front.

Comment: we are doing in slightly difference: when we catch the PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED  instead of creating new order, we redirect to the original approve url to go through the payment flow again.

Comment: Yeah, that works too, but since it's the final step, we need the `user_action` to be PAY_NOW instead of CONTINUE. Also, we need to handle the returning user slightly differently in that case. I guess we could also just patch it accordingly and then redirect to the original approval URL. Either way it's a bit annoying, but it is what it is. At least it works :)